# Does android GCM registration changes?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

Does android GCM registationid changes?
As I understood, It's not permanent. When internet connection is on it's send an onRegister signal. But what about when there is no internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registration ID can change at any time which is why you need to implement `GCMBaseIntentService` and override `onRegistered` so that anytime a new registration ID is sent to you, you can get it.

If there is no internet then obviously you wont be able to get the new ID

Comment: For sending notification Google tries again few times if there is no internet. Does the same happen in this case for renewing the registrationID? I couldn't find any doc which mentions the case of internet unavailability case for renewing the ID. Can you plese point to the same ?

Comment: I dont know I have never actually waited for it to happen since it does not happen that much

Comment: You're right it doesn't happen frequently. I read on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838654/handling-registration-id-changes-in-google-cloud-messaging-on-android/16839326 thread in comments that for someone it happened in few hours of obtaining the an ID.