# Registration GCM Broacast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

According with this:

> Note that Google may periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should design your >Android application with the understanding that the >com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent may be called multiple times.

I'm using the new GCM ( Google Play Services ), so i thinked to use a Broadcast Receiver for this intent:

```
<receiver 
        android:name="com.example.gcmclient.RegistrationHandler"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I would use this Broadcast Receiver to be able to detect that Registration_ID is changed and send it to my server. Can i do this or i am on a wrong way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling registration ID changes in Google Cloud Messaging on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838654/handling-registration-id-changes-in-google-cloud-messaging-on-android)

Comment: I read that post, but i'm curios to know if i can follow this way.

Comment: It will work, but based on the Demo GCM client application suggested by Google, it is not necessary (as mentioned in the answer of the duplicated question). Furthermore, it might interfere with the Google Play Services registration, since your added BroadcastReceiver may intercept the response of that registration.