# GCM now losing Registration IDs

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have several apps on Google Play that extensively use GCM and they have all been working very well for quite some time now.  But, all of a sudden (Aug 12, 2015), GCM is sometimes returning "NotRegistered" when my server posts a message to it.

This is happening just occasionally but that is often enough to cause big problems as the messaging can no longer be trusted.

The last part of the web response stream is: [{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}

I log the registration id along with the response stream and the registration id that I attempted to use is the same one that has always been used for that phone.  My apps get a new registration id when they are first ran so it is necessary for the application to be uninstalled and reinstalled to make the app work again.  Has something changed?

Oddly, (or not) the problem has only occurred on phones running 5.1 lollipop.  Did I possibly miss another breaking change?
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using *GoogleCloudMessaging* to [register](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid), one possibility is that these users received an upgrade of your app. See the latest edit to Eran's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838654/handling-registration-id-changes-in-google-cloud-messaging-on-android/16839326#16839326).They will need to re-register with GCM. Consider using the latest registration method using Instance IDs, which has a listener for token refresh when needed.

Comment: my version compare was not working so when version changed, the app no longer got messages.  I read about the new registration methods. hmmmm.