# why always Gcm Id is expired in Android?

Tags: android

I create GCM cloud Messages for App, after 10 days it is am not getting push notifications because its showing android GCM is as expired . What is solutions for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling registration ID changes in Google Cloud Messaging on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838654/handling-registration-id-changes-in-google-cloud-messaging-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

GCM server usually refreshes So your old registration id could be expired the registration ids. Whenever this happens is not documented anywhere. But you will get notification whenever this happens.

[See here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)