# How does gcm server generates registration id? is it unique for every app in device or unique per device?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm not sure that if gcm creates unique **registration id**  for every application, would it not be cumbersome to have so many mappings on  its server?

Comment: Bro, you are talking about google, which can display over a million results in less than a millisecond. They have highly advanced mapping techniques. And when it comes about registration IDs, I assume that you dont want the notification meant for Mr. A to reach Mr. B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling registration ID changes in Google Cloud Messaging on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838654/handling-registration-id-changes-in-google-cloud-messaging-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

The GCM Server isn't the one responsible for generating the Registration IDs (a.k.a registration tokens, Instance ID). The one that generates it is the Instance ID API service. You can refer to the [Registering Client Apps docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration) for more details to it.

And it is unique per instance of the app as mentioned in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/):

> Instance ID provides a unique ID per instance of your apps.

Cumbersome, yes, but it still just depends on the number of users of your app.

On a side note, GCM has a newer version called [firebase-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/firebase-cloud-messaging). Do check it out.