# Xcode 8 and Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, xcode8

I have an app that I made with Xcode 7.3. I updated to Xcode 8 and now the latest release of my app, it seems my Firebase Cloud Messaging has quit.

I can see the token is getting generated and uploaded to my server but my device does not receive any notifications. If I delete the app and then reinstall the older version that is currently on the iTunes store, I am able to receive the notifications again.

I do not understand what changed in Xcode 8 to make my FCM quit. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No way to determine anything based on what you provided. Was there any change in your implementation (server/client app)? If you haven't really changed anything, feel like the code is fine, and FCM just stopped working, I suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure either your push function not work or it is FCM problem with new version of Xcode ? As I face the same problem recently, i check step by step. The first is make sure my APNs work properly, then test FCM by sending it via Firebase console page.

In case Firebase warning that device unregistered, here is solution:
And as of EDIT (04.24.2014) : as per

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839326/313113

tokens do not refresh after a certain period. And it seems there is a bug when the user upgrades the app and you send a notification at the same time when the upgrade happens, the token gets unregistered, so you have to register again after an app upgrade.

So I uninstall app and get new token ID which work like before (iOS <9)