# Android: FCM java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error on some devices

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use `FCM` in my project

It work correct on Sony xperia, Galaxy S6, Motorola and more. But on Galaxy S3 i get `java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error

Time of Galaxy S3 is auto and google play is updated

Internet connection is strong and i connected to open internet without proxy

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325099/service-not-available-some-devices-on-android-gcm). This [error](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging#ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE) means that your device can't read the response or there was a 500/503 from the server. You should use exponential back off and retry.

Comment: @abielita My app is crashing with 
`Fatal Exception: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException
java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` while try to retrieve the token from result. so my concern is how to prevent the app from crashing with this error?

Comment: before accessing the result check for 
if(task!=null && task.isSuccessful())){ task.getResult()} 
this check will avoid app from getting crashed

Answer (score 23):

This error is caused when the device is unable to register to Firebase. Make sure the internet is working when this code is called. And put the code within try-catch to stop app from crashing.

**Edit:**
Either add an internet connection check before registering the device or fetching token.
Or
wrap the Fetch token code in try-catch block to prevent app from crashing.

Example:

1. Adding the internet connection check code:

   ```
    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
      getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

      return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && 
      cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
   }
   ```
2. Internet check and move ahead.

   ```
   if (isNetworkConnected())
      refreshToken(this);
   ```

Comment: kindly provide a sample try-catch here... thank you

Comment: Also, in my case, the problem might be, when phone connected to Charles proxy.

Comment: I turned on the internet and it works. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that you have included

> task.isSuccessful()

check in your code inside overriden onComplete method like this -

> FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken() .addOnCompleteListener(new
> OnCompleteListener() {
>
> ```
>         @Override
>         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
>             if(task.isSuccessful()) {
>                 fcmToken = task.getResult();
>             }
>         }
>     });
> ```

If not, whenever a network error or some other issue occurs at the time of registration of fcm token, then you may get FIS_Authentication_Failed or SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE type of errors.

Answer (score 7):

Check following:

1- Internet connection

2- Phone date/time to be correct

Comment: 2- Phone date/time to be correct
Why, it can cause this problem?

Comment: Date and time was the issue, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem was in `Google Mobile Services` app. After clearing its data problem disappeared.

I found a key for problem after launching on another device, where issue doesn't reproduces.

Comment: This resolved it for me after taking the following steps:

- Ensure the SHA1 of my android app on play store has been added to the list of unrestricted apps.
- Ensured the google_oauth_client for the play store credentials is both used in the code and on the google-services.json file. 
- Ensured  the SHA1 of my android app on play store has been added to firebase.
- Then I cleared the cache and storage of google play services app on my pixel 6.
- Uninstalled and installed the app from playstore and VOILA, the app was able to retrieve token.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still facing an error, please try adding the getToken and other firebase messaging calls in useEffect and add `messaging` as its dependency.

Sometimes, the app is trying to invoke these methods before the messaging library is getting initialized, so try wrapping your code in useEffect with messaging as dependency.

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

React.useEffect(() => {
  // Get the token
  const token = await messaging().getToken();
  // other messaging operations
}, [messaging])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this code from `void main()` and putting it somewhere else; e.g., after the user is successfully logged in, or inside the `init` function on the first page:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
final fCMToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
```