# com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.handleResponse (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:7)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting a crash while opening the app on some devices. I am not able to reproduce it on my device. But I am getting a list of crashes in Firebase Crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

This is the message I am getting from Crashlytics.

Below is the full message :

```
Caused by java.io.IOException
SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.handleResponse (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:7)
com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.lambda$extractResponseWhenComplete$0$GmsRpc (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:1)
com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc$$Lambda$1.then (Unknown Source:2)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:3)
com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc$$Lambda$0.execute
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:5)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:3)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:8)
com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzz.execute
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:5)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:3)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzq.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:9)
com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzs.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:7)
com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzf.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:45)
com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzi.handleMessage (Unknown Source:2)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:103)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:226)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7592)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I am also getting the same crash in some other devices with a different message:

```
Caused by com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzp
Timed out waiting for response
com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzf.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:94)
com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzl.run (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:2)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:462)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:2)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

I have already tried some solutions from [Android: FCM java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208426/android-fcm-java-io-ioexception-service-not-available-error-on-some-devices/53919064)

but it's not fixed.

Anyone knows its solution please help me.

Comment: Have you had any luck fixing this?

Comment: In my case I see this error logs                                                                            Caused by java.io.IOException
TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS
com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.handleResponse