# What are the cases where a registration ID of GCM changes?

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing a web push notification system using Google Cloud Messaging (*only web*). I am using a GCM registration id to send the push notification in an Android device.

Can anybody tell me if there are any cases or scenarios that the GCM registration id will be changed for a device?

FYI, I would like to share my current knowledge:

1. The GCM registration id will be changed if the application is updated or re-installed.
2. If the device OS is updated.

My system design is as follows:

First, I register the registration id of the device in my database *?* 
(*This is the only one time my client access my site and be able to get the registration ID and where I save it*).

Then, I send a notification after a month or later (*it depends, maybe even after 3 months*).

Here are my questions:

1. If the device OS was updated in during that duration, does the device id change?
2. If the Chrome browser is updated or reinstalled, does the device registration id change?
3. If the registration id does change (because of one of the reasons above), how can I send a push notification to the desired device?

Appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043298/android-gcm-registration-id-change), I think it is related to your question.