# DEVICE_UNREGISTERED GCM nack message received

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Java Server is receiving `DEVICE_UNREGISTERED` GCM nack message when it is sending downstream message to iOS client. The same `iOS` client app was working earlier with development push certificate.

But now I have created `iOS` client build with in house enterprise certificate. This production app is able to send the upstream message to java server. However, when server try to send downstream message, server is getting `DEVICE_UNREGISTERED` nack message from GCM.

But our `iOS` client app is successfully registered and connected to `GCM`. It has also received the `GCM` registration token.

We have android client `app.Downstream/upstream` messages are working properly for android.

Any help is appreciated to resolve this issue..

**GCM Request from the java server:**

```
<message>
    <gcm xmlns='google:mobile:data'>{"to":"l9qEErT1AFE:APA91bEjR4R-eETscNQ7Nw-WeqAIzyisDsY79a_EkKhUACXGAzDoYnRyL7Ge6ca9MSfgZ-fGc7NDevTtI7NozOn126CN5AhpbaZDfuZoWFccqF2ibsdKptFGgxbZpIIK5eVK0DILrCsR","delivery_receipt_requested":true,"priority":"high","data":{"toolconfig":"{\n \"ecb\" : \"app.onNotificationGCM\",\n \"action\" : \"ping\",\n \"senderID\" : \"152585324066\"\n}","action":"com.XXX.XXX.XXXX.ECHO"},"notification":{"sound":"default"},"message_id":"1026274672"}</gcm>
</message>
```

**NACK Response from the GCM:**

```
<message>
    <gcm xmlns='google:mobile:data'>{"message_type":"nack","from":"l9qEErT1AFE:APA91bEjR4R-eETscNQ7Nw-WeqAIzyisDsY79a_EkKhUACXGAzDoYnRyL7Ge6ca9MSfgZ-fGc7NDevTtI7NozOn126CN5AhpbaZDfuZoWFccqF2ibsdKptFGgxbZpIIK5eVK0DILrCsR","message_id":"1026274672","error":"DEVICE_UNREGISTERED","error_description":""}</gcm>
</message>
```

Comment: Posting some code snippets, the payload, the response your seeing would help a lot.

Comment: I have added the request and response JSON ..

Comment: This problem seems to have varied causes, but mainly points to Instance ID. Try to check this [Github post](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/49). Some users cite that it may have something to do with Instance ID not working with the deprecated gcm.register() method. Others stated that an external library may be causing the problem.

Comment: Have you seen these before? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16839326/4625829, http://stackoverflow.com/a/17899972/4625829